# How do you iterate through an array and delete an element?

Tags: java, array

I have an array and I can iterate through it. I know that it is impossible to change the size of an array; however, how do I take out a certain element that I not want in the array anymore?

Example: if the user chooses to delete the certain element how do I go about writing this out in my code?

Comment: How often would you want to do this?  Java arrays are fast for a small set of operations and slow for others.  They are most efficient when the contents are constant in size and predictable in the location of any desired value. If you often want to remove elements, you may be better off with a map.  If you often iterate over the array to find a particular value, you may be better off with a list (or map).  If you want to store values at constantly predictable locations but may or may not store a value, then you *could* use objects rather than primitives, allowing null (but map would be better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Java Collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) is something that you should browse.  There are also some types that aren't array-like (Set and Map) but you will find that you will use them often.  There are many different types of collections, and some have advantages over others for certain types of operations.

### Classic arrays

First, the thing that *isn't* in the collections framework.  The Array.  Not ArrayList, but rather the classic `int[]`.  The advantage of the array is that it closely maps to what memory is.  `foo[42]` is to lookup.  Many system level calls that give you a fixed number of items are arrays and they are good to know.  `"1,2,3".split(",")` returns back an array for example.

The problem with arrays is that they aren't that flexible.  Adding an element to the end of an array that already is at is maximum capacity means allocating a new, larger array and then doing an `System.arraycopy()` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))) to copy all the elements from one array to another array in a timely manner.

To *remove* an element from the list you need to remove it and then walk the remainder of the list to have everything be contagious again.  If you want to remove `foo[4]` from the list, you then assign `foo[4] = foo[5]` and `foo[5] = foo[6]` and so on down to the end of the list.  Thats if you have to do it by hand.  You can also use that `System.arraycopy` mentioned to do it for you given the right set of arguments.  Something like:

```
System.arraycopy(foo,5,foo,4,foo.length - 4);
```

I might have that wrong, but thats the general idea.  Copying the array back on itself.  It *should* work.

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination array.

### Lists

As you see, arrays are a bit awkward to work with.  You've got do it all by hand.  Its good to know, but a pain to practice.  There are two lists that are in common use that make this easier for you.  For the most part, Lists *look* like arrays.

```
List<Integer> foo = ...;
foo.get(4);
foo.remove(5);
```

You call methods on them, but you are fetching the 4th element via method call instead of via direct access through the array.  See that `foo.remove(5)`.  Thats it.  You're done. You have removed an element from the list and deleted it. Much easier to remember.

#### ArrayList

The ArrayList is backed by an Array.  This means that doing `foo.get(4)` runs fast, but `foo.add(42, foo.size()+1)` is likely to be slow because it has to do all of that moving of things around to allocate a new list (yes, I know that the list can be longer than the size, but lets assume that its the same size as its actual list).

Instead of having to remember how to do all the shuffling, you've got nice methods to do your work for you.  It doesn't mean that its not done (the work is still done behind the scenes of the interface), but its something that you don't have to worry about.

So, the ArrayList is for:

- fast get (O(1))
- slow remove and insert (O(length))
- slow append when full (O(length))

#### LinkedList

For some reason, everyone's goto list implementation is the ArrayList.  I don't know why. Many times when I'm working with Lists, the LinkedList is the one that is more applicable.  You keep adding things to the end.  Rarely do you want the n<sup>th</sup> element.  You just want to iterate over them.

This is what the LinkedList is good for.  It does fast remove and append and its iterator is just as fast as the ArrayList.  Its just if you want `foo.get(400)` its going to be a bit slower than the ArrayList implement.

The LinkedList is also a Deque too, but people forget about that.  That lets you access the LinkedList as a double ended queue (nice for implementing a Stack or Queue).

So, if you are just appending and iterating, the LinkedList is for you.

- Get is slowish (O(index))
- Fast append (O(1))
- Remove and insert is slowish (O(index))

Note that the O(index) there is a bit of an award bit.  It will index depending on which way is faster to get there (from the end or start).  So if the LinkedList is 100 long, and you get(10), it starts from the start.  If you ask for get(90), it starts from the end. So get(index) is never more than get(length/2), but thats all just factors that don't matter when looking at Big O.

Comment: How does this answer the actual question?  I realise it is a naive question, but you're providing general knowledge which might improve his general understanding of Java collections while still leaving him to grope for the right answer.  It really would help to give a specific answer either based on this extra information or preceding it.

Comment: @itsbruce its right up there at the top.  There's the System.arrayCopy mentioned.  There is also the paragraph starting at "To remove an element from the list you need to remove it and then walk the remainder of the list to have everything be contagious again."  Note that if the OP wanted specific code advice, it would have been better to post on Stack Overflow for that than on Programmers.SE where we are dealing more with the conceptual issues which I fully address (and the various abstractions with the List interface).

Comment: Fair enough but I do think the OP's question implies a basic misunderstanding or misuse of arrays which needs specific addressing if true.  But I've my own answer for that so no worries.

Comment: I'm afraid your discussion of LinkedList is inaccurate. Firstly, on a theoretical level you can't make that distinction between `O(length)` and `O(index)`. Yes, your index is probably on average length/2, but `O(length/2)` = `O(length)`. The fact is, all the operations you discuss have the same big-O for both LinkedList and ArrayList. The LinkedList only has a better big-O if you somehow already have the iterator for an individual element you want to operate on. That's true for some algorithms, but its rare.

Comment: On the practical level, ArrayList are much faster to iterate because all you have to do is increment a counter, which is very fast. Linked Lists have to dereference a pointer and jump to a completely different place in memory. Both of those are slow operations. ArrayLists do have to move data for some operations, but moving blocks of data while O(n) is a fast operation. Its actually much faster then the LinkedList iteration process.

Comment: For more details see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist, or a do google search for "don't use linked lists". 

The fact is, there are cases for LinkedList, but they are rare. You certainly shouldn't be suggested that novices default to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you must really do this using an array, then you will need to:

- copy all elements of the array after the element being deleted down by one position to cover the removed element.
- resize your array to be smaller by one element.

Copying elements down by one position can be done either by writing a loop yourself, or by invoking `System.arraycopy( src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)`.

Resizing the array can be done like this: `myArray = Arrays.copyOf( myArray, newCapacity )`.

That having been said, if you have any need to manipulate the length of the array, then definitely go with `ArrayList` instead of using arrays. This wheel has already been invented.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an array of reference types, then the contents of each cell will default to **null**.  If you have placed a real value in a cell, you can effectively "delete" it by replacing it with **null**.  As long as your code checks for **null** values, then replacing with **null** can count as a deletion.  But this is an inefficient use of arrays, whose primary advantage is speed in accessing indexed values whose number does not change.  If your "collection" may or not contain certain values then a map or list would be better.

If it is an array of primitives (**int**, **byte** and so on) then you cannot delete contents.  You could insert the *default* value (**0** for numeric types, **false** for booleans) but that probably is not useful to you.  The best you can do is copy all elements apart from that one into a new array.  Something you could *also* do for reference types by copying everything that isn't **null**.

So the important question is this:

1. Do you want to know whether a specific array index contains a meaningful value?
2. **Or** are you simply interested in all the values currently in the array?

If the answer is 1, then for primitive types the answer is **no**.  For **reference types** you could replace them with **null**, but really, a map would be better because then you can delete the key.

If the answer is 2, then you can copy all the other cells into a new array.

So which is it?

Comment: I definitely wanted number two.  Thank you.  I know that is what I want to, I am just not sure on how to do it.

Comment: Well, depending on the usage pattern (how often you change the dataset and in which way), simple arrays really may not be appropriate.  Between my answer and @MichaelT's, I hope there's some help.  One important thing to consider: copying to a new array means any reference to the old array will *not* see the update.